# Swift -How does a for loop finish before the line under it?

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, control-flow

I'm a self taught developer. I never went to college or took any classes that taught me the theory of programming or any of the underlying concepts. I just know how to build iOS apps (via books, videos, meetups, and practice) and I don't know any of that other stuff as Apple has taken care of most of that using it's Xcode SDK (so would most compilers) so I don't need to know any of that stuff.

One thing that has always perplexed me though:

If these 2 print statements ran, they would print in the correct order from top to bottom (`control flow`)

```
print("I will print first")
print("I will print second")
```

If a `for-loop` ran it would print all the numbers in the exact order until the condition is met:

```
for num in 1...10 {

    print(num)
    if num == 9 {
        print("done") // the for-loop has to iterate 9 times for it to print
        break
    }
}
```

**This is what bugs me out.** How is it that if I have a long running `for-loop` and a print statement after it, the for-loop finishes before the print statement underneath of it runs?

```
for num in 1...10000000 {

    if num == 10000000 {
        print("why does this print") // the for-loop has to iterate 10 million times for it to print
    }
}

print("before this prints")
```

The loop has to run 10 million times before that print statement inside of it prints. How is it that those 10 million iterations are faster then just printing that `"before this prints"` print statement underneath of it?

Forgive me if this is a question that it is assumed I should know but nothing I've ever read or watched tackled this question.

Comment: This is nothing about being ___faster___ or ___slower___. As you have said something about **control flow** yourself, you should realize that control flow here. When control enters the `for` loop, it stays inside the for loop upon completing/breaking that loop. Anything after that loop will be executed after that loop ends.

Comment: @nayem Thanks for the clarity. You should’ve posted this as an answer. Basically your saying it has to finish what’s inside the for loop before it moves on to the next line. I never knew that. I thought everything just flowed in order. I don’t know the for-loop actually stops the program.

Comment: Well, @Lance I have written an extensive answer to supplement my comment above. Take your time to read that.

Comment: @nayem I’ll upvote it, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fundamentally all operations are executed sequentially as stated in Oleg's answer.

What you have to understand is that special things like `for loop` statements or `if statements` or other, are sort of instructions for the runtime. And when the code executtion gets to the point where it encounters `for loop` instruction it goes on and on inside of a for loop. It just knows that this thing inside of for loop `{}` should be executed `n` times before it can continue. So when the for loop finishes, it goes to the next line of code and does whatever instruction is there.

This is not very deep explanation, but I was trying to be simplistic. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for a much clearer explanation. I’m going to upvote because your answer brought some clarity to my question although it didn’t give me a clear answer. nayem’s comment under the question was what I was looking for but your answer helped makes his answer clearer for me. Thank you!

Comment: I reread your answer again. This is what I was looking for. Nayem’s answer was just a little simpler but you said the same exact thing he said. You actually said it first so that’s why I picked yours. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is executed sequentially.

If you want the calculations not delay the main thread, use another thread.

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    for num in 1...10000000 {

        if num == 10000000 {
            print("why does this print") // the for-loop has to iterate 10 million times for it to print
        }
    }
}

print("before this prints")
```

Output:

```
before this prints
why does this print
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I never said anything about the main thread or it printing in a different order. I don’t want it to print in another order. I want to know why or better yet how the 10 million iterations run faster then the line underneath of it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good reason why for, while, do-while are called **loop** because execution control keep looping inside block of for or while loop untill one of it's condition met...

for example

```
for num in 1...4 {

    print("line"\(num))
}
print("line5")
```

but for compiler So it's sequential like

```
line1

line2

line3

line4


line5
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to give you the idea as simple as it can be in my comment to your question. That should answer your question. You've got some other answers as well, though, some of them are pretty vague compared to your understanding level as far.

For the sake of completeness and to clarify the usage of `for` (or any other loop) I'm extending the idea in this answer as simple as it can be.

`for` is a shorthand syntax for executing statement(s) repeatedly. The code in your question can be written without this shorthand syntax as:

```
/// checkpoint #1: variable initialization
var num = 1

/// checkpoint #2: condition checking
if num <= 10000000 { //condition true
    if num == 10000000 { //at this point, num equals to 1, so condition is false
        print("why does this print") //doesn't execute
    }
    /// checkpoint #3: increment value of the variable
    num = num + 1 //at this point, num equals to 2
}

if num <= 10000000 { //condition true
    if num == 10000000 { //at this point, num equals to 2, so condition is false
        print("why does this print") //doesn't execute
    }
    num = num + 1 //at this point, num equals to 3
}

if num <= 10000000 { //condition true
    if num == 10000000 { //at this point, num equals to 3, so condition is false
        print("why does this print") //doesn't execute
    }
    num = num + 1 //at this point, num equals to 4
}

. . .
// upto the point where the above repeated lines reach 10000000 if counted
. . .

if num <= 10000000 { //condition true
    if num == 10000000 { //at this point, num equals to 10000000, so condition is true
        print("why does this print") //this time it executes
    }
    num = num + 1 //at this point, num equals to 10000000 + 1
}

if num <= 10000000 { //condition false
    //doesn't execute anything inside this conditional block
    if num == 10000000 {
        print("why does this print")
    }
    num = num + 1
}

// this is the termination point if loop was used

//after executing the previous statements, this line will be executed
print("before this prints")
```

As programmers, we are intelligent to identify the repeating statements. And we are intelligent enough to make the above code shorter and simpler. This is when we introduce `loop`. Find the repeating block and put them inside a loop.

---

Did you notice the repeating statements above? Let's put it here one more time:

```
if num <= 10000000 {
    if num == 10000000 {
        print("why does this print")
    }
    num = num + 1
}
```

---

Look this code in **Swift**:

```
for num in 1...10000000 {
    if num == 10000000 {
        print("why does this print")
    }
}
print("before this prints")
```

can be written in other language (say, **C**):

```
for(int num = 1; num <= 10000000; num++) {
    if(num == 10000000) {
        printf("why does this print");
    }
}
printf("before this prints");
```

The above loop in **C** can be broken into pieces what you can compare to the checkpoints I mentioned in the first block of code:

```
for(int num = 1/*checkpoint #1*/; num <= 10000000/*checkpoint #2*/; num++/*checkpoint #3*/)
```

Now, as the checkpoints are met by the `for` loop's syntax itself, only remaining part is:

```
if num == 10000000 {
    print("why does this print")
}
```

And you put this part inside the curly braces `{ ... }` of a `for` loop.

---

---

I hope this extensive explanation should give you the overall idea behind a loop. And now you should be able to understand the **control flow** of the code execution.

Comment: I actually figured it out based on your and @inokey’s answer. It’s not hard to understand I just wasn’t aware it worked that way. Thanks

Comment: @LanceSamaria oh well, glad to know that. Just put my effort in writing a lengthy explanation for nothing then. Cheers!

Comment: It’s never for nothing. The next person who comes along can use it 

Answer (score 0):

The programs are executed sequentially in programming language, have learnt starting from C language.  Only conditional statements can change the execution flow otherwise it is line by line.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of `closure` in iOS, `closure` is a piece of code that took time for `execution`. `Closure` does not held the program and run separately until it's got finish. Other lines of code are going to execute parallel. So that's why your statement is printing before the `loop`. if you want to print after loop then you should do this:

```
    DispatchQueue.main.sync {
       for num in 1...10000000 {

           if num == 10000000 {
            print("why does this print") // the for-loop has to iterate 10 million times for it to print
            }
        }
    }
    print("before this prints")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not that the latter print function is slower than the for loop. If you run your for loop and the latter print() function at the same time, you will be able to see that. In the above code, it is just a matter of sequence. Let me try to put it before you through a simple example below.

Suppose you are at location A and want to go to location B at a distance of 10 km. You have started on foot to reach the destination (location B). Now, while on your journey, you can make the following decisions:

1. You can complete the entire trip and reach location B on foot (will take more time).
2. At any point during your journey, you can choose to take a lift on a vehicle and complete the rest of the distance (faster than #1).
3. At any point during your journey to location B, you can decide to cancel the journey altogether.

There might be some other scenarios as well. However, in any scenario, can you reach location B before you cover the distance between location A and location B?

Consider the for loop here as that journey between location A and location B, and the print function is a jar of sweet candies you will get at location B.

I hope that makes it clear. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

All loops (like for, while, do-while etc) are synchronous and control flow is from top to bottom. Loop will continue to run until its terminate condition is reached.
That is why first loop execution will finish and then your external print statement will execute.
Now to make the controller understand that some job you want to run asynchronously you can do like this:

```
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    for num in 1...10000000 {

        if num == 10000000 {
            print("why does this print") // the for-loop has to iterate 10 million times for it to print
        }
    }
}

print("before this prints")
```

**Output:**

before this prints

why does this print

By that above line of code `DispatchQueue.global().async` you are telling controller that block of code you can run in background and when you will finish just tell me the answer, that is why you can see below print statement execute earlier than the million loop result displays.